# Android - problem parsing date

Tags: android, date-format

I am using the following piece of code to parse a date -

```
DateFormat dateFormatIn = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.S'Z'");
String ts = "2011-06-15T17:34:09.291Z";
String timestamp = dateFormatIn.format(ts);
```

It throws me an IllegalArgumentException. Any idea what is the right way to go about it?

Comment: whats the complete error msg?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DateFormat.format() expects a `Date` as parameter and not a `String`.

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormat.html#format(java.util.Date)

U need to use [DateFormat.parse()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29) to get the Date